# Javascript Regex to check repeating words pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

How to parse string no check is it in valid pattern?

1. I need to find are there words AND or OR
2. I need to check are they surrounded by another words, but not AND or OR

If it is valid i will build query.

Examples:

```
a and b or c -> valid
a and or b   -> invalid
a or and b   -> invalid
a or b       -> valid
a and b or   -> invalid
and b or c   -> invalid
```

Comment: "*I need X*" is not a question.

Comment: Whats your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^(?=.*(?:and|or).*$)(?!(?:"\s*")*\s*(?:and|or))(?!.*(?:and|or)\s*(?:"\s*")*$)(?!.*and\s+or)(?!.*or\s+and).*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BMzk9v/3)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Start of the String
- `(?!\s*(?:and|or))` - Negative lookahead - makes sure that `and` or `or` are not present at the beginning of the string preceded by 0+ spaces
- `(?!.*(?:and|or)\s*$)` - Negative lookahead - makes sure that `and` or `or` are not present at the end of the string followed by 0+ spaces
- `(?!.*and\s+or)` - makes sure `or` does not follow immediately after `and` and 1+ spaces
- `(?!.*or\s+and)` - makes sure 'and' does not follow immediately after `or` and 1+ spaces
- .+ - match anything but new line characters
- `$` - End of String

Update:

[image]

Comment: Why it matches all line in regex101?

Comment: Check again. It matches only for the Valid matches. https://regex101.com/r/BMzk9v/1

Comment: Nope, still the same.

Comment: Full match 70-91 `a or b       -> valid`

Comment: Did you check the link I added? I have also added the screenshot in the answer.

Comment: Basically it doesn't work, because eventually "a" or  " " also valid.

Comment: You did not provide that as an input. I have updated the answer and the link. Check it.

Comment: No, you dont understand - string or whitespace only also get valid. This is why this task not so trivial.

Comment: What a f... Is it your native language? :D

Comment: No Sir. I just try. :)

Answer (score 1):

Would you be fine with a non-regex solution?

Try this

```js
function isValid( str )
{
  return str.split(/\s*and\s*|\s*or\s*/g).filter( function(item){
     return item.length == 0 ;
  }).length == 0;
}

console.log( isValid( "a and b or c" ) );
console.log( isValid( "a and or b" ) );
console.log( isValid( "a or and b" ) );
console.log( isValid( "a or b" ) );
console.log( isValid( "a and b or" ) );
console.log( isValid( "and b or c" ) );

console.log( isValid( "a and b c" ) );
```

`isValid` first split the string based on **and** and **or**, then checks if the returned array has an empty element or not.

Comment: It's wrong, because second one should be valid.
It will generate query from "a" and "b c"

Comment: yes, now looks right. If valid i just need to split all string by " " and i will have all parts for query.

Comment: Same issue on this, "a" or " " or "1" also valid, which is wrong.

Comment: @user3462947 you need to either add all possible examples of valid and invalid strings or specify the rules of what is valid/invalid.